# GoogleSafeBrowsing api using safebrowsinglookup library

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api

I'm very new to programming and want to check if client url is safe or suspected of malware.
Library Link: https://github.com/acastaner/safebrowsinglookup

```
LookupClient client = new LookupClient("someApiKey", "someClientName");
ResponseType response = client.Lookup(url);
switch (response)
   {
       case ResponseType.OK:
           consoleMessage = "URL appears to be safe.";
           break;

       case ResponseType.MALWARE:
           consoleMessage = "URL is suspected of hosting malware.";
           break;

       case ResponseType.MALWARE_UNWANTED:
           consoleMessage = "URL is suspected of hosting malware and unwanted software.";
           break;

           case ResponseType.PHISHING:
           consoleMessage = "URL is suspected of phishing.";
           break;

       case ResponseType.PHISHING_MALWARE:
           consoleMessage = "URL is suspected of phishing and hosting malware.";
           break;

       case ResponseType.PHISHING_MALWARE_UNWANTED:
           consoleMessage = "URL is suspected of phishing and hosting malware and unwanted software.";
           break;

       case ResponseType.PHISHING_UNWANTED:
           consoleMessage = "URL is suspected of phishing and hosting unwanted software.";
           break;

       case ResponseType.UNWANTED:
           consoleMessage = "URL is suspected of hosting unwanted software.";
           break;

   }
```

I'm getting error like

> Cannot implicity convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task to SafeBrowsingLookup.ResponseType" in "ResponseType response = client.Lookup(url);

Comment: add the code that you get this error...

Comment: @Aristos I'm getting error in <ResponseType response = client.Lookup(url);> line.